# Opening multiple screens in a linux terminal using a script or command

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, tmux, split

I want to open screens vertically and horizontally.

I have used the following:

- tmux

  ctrl + b then %
  ctrl + b then "
- screen

  ctrl + a then S
  ctrl + a then |

But, is it possible to open a screen using a shell script or command rather than interactive keypresses?

### Partial Solution

I have found the following script, but it only opens horizontally and does not appear to be able to open a screen both horizontally and vertically.

```
$ cat my_screenrc
screen 
split
focus down
screen 
split
focus down
screen
focus bottom
$ screen -c my_screenrc
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand everything… it's not Ctrl+b+%, it's Ctrl+b, then %. (press Ctrl, press b, release b, release Ctrl, press %, release %). "I have found this" → where? (maybe there is some precision in the place you found this). "but I wanted…script?" isn't a clear question. And, do you want to use Tmux or Screen?

Comment: @ewen-goisot : it's Ctrl+b, then %. This thing I want to implement by shell script or terminal command . I don't want to open new terminal by keystroke . I can use any of the two command tmux or screen.

Comment: Vikash, are you using `gnome-terminal` by any chance ?  If so, there is a built-in solution that will essentially do away with the need to script things up , such as in @bk2204 's (otherwise perfectly good) answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple approaches you can take here.  The first, and easiest, is to use a tool like [tmuxinator](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator) to handle your tmux configuration if you always want the same thing.

You can also script tmux from the command line.  For example, you could do this to create a single new session with a new window with a 4-way split:

```
#!/bin/sh

tmux source-file <<EOF
new-session
split-window -h
split-window -v
select-pane -L
split-window -v
EOF
```

The tmux manual pages describes the commands you can use; it is intentionally designed to be highly scriptable.  You can see [the Ruby script I've used for this](https://github.com/bk2204/dotfiles/blob/dev/bin/tmux-generate-session).